# US entry in Atlanta airport (ATL) together with a US citizen

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, atl

I will soon travel to the US for the first time.

I am not a US citizen, but I will travel together with one.

We will land in ATL and then proceed to a connecting flight. I know I will have to clear customs in ATL.

My ESTA application has been approved, but I read that since I never have travelled to the US before, I will have to clear immigration through a old-fashioned booth with a immigration officer, and I won't be able to use the electronic kiosks.

As my travel companion is a citizen, they'll not be subject to this restriction.

What is the best course of action? Should they queue with me, or should we proceed our separate ways?

I'd like to proceed together, but I don't know if it is allowed.

Comment: What's your relationship to your companion? If you're married, [this answer applies](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102748/us-border-with-british-wife).

Comment: I suppose it could be different in ATL, but even if you use the booths, you pass by a real human, unless you have global entry, which I assume you don't.

Comment: You may want to check my question: [Crossing a border with an infant of a different citizenship](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/133620/51569). I called the CBP office in Charlotte, which is my port of entry, and their answer was (without an hesitation) that we (a citizen and a non-citizen) had to go through visitors if we wanted to stay together.

Comment: @Clément on the other hand, in New York and Newark, I have been repeatedly and consistently told the contrary: that I and my non-US family should use the US citizens' line.  So it seems that the only way to find out what to do in Atlanta is to ask an officer in Atlanta.

Comment: Federico: actually, you are supposed to submit a joint customs declaration if you live in the same household and have any sort of relationship beyond being roommates.  It's not limited to spouses.  A joint customs declaration implies going to passport control together.

Comment: I've entered as a non-US citizen with my citizen child twice in the last 5 years (Chicago and Washington) and both times had to go through the visitor proceedings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Atlanta it is a big hall for the Passport checks (not customs, that comes later after you collect your bags).

For first timers, they will take your fingerprints and photo at the booth where the officer checks the passport.

It is very swift and easy. I don't remember exactly if there were restrictions about who may use the line, but I don't think so.

Comment: There are indeed different lines for citizens and non-citizens at immigration in Atlanta (and also separate lines for Global Entry, Mobile Passport, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can both go to the same passport check booth, but if you are asked to go to additional screening, whomever is with you will likely not be allowed to accompany you, even if it is your spouse. That person will then have to wait for you outside the immigration area.

Comment: Yeah. It would be nicer to wait together in the queue than on the restaurant at arrival. Near the split of the two queue usually you will find an officer which tell people on what queue to go. You can ask and get confirmation (and maybe to the US queue).

Comment: It also helps to be together if one of you needs help or information of the other. Like the address you will stay, or your relationship with your travel companion (being cross verified with the other.)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi in my experience, the people telling you which line to go to are airport staff, not CBP officers, and they do not seem to have any training to deal with substantive questions. I have been told on more than one occasion to ignore them because they don't know what they're talking about.  So take any information they give you with a grain of salt.

Comment: @phoog: yes, but you have an argument to immigration officers if the quick one was the wrong one (so not bad faith). In any case usually (always) staff are nice, just that sometime they are extremely slow (and too much chatty).