# US which Immigration line with girlfriend?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, atlanta

Me (US citizen) traveling with fiancee (EU citizen been to the US several times with ESTA) to Atlanta.

Should we use the visitors line together or can she go through the citizens line with me?

Most importantly we dont want to be seperated. Dont really care which line we go through.

Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you both just using the kiosks?

Comment: Related: [US entry in Atlanta airport (ATL) together with a US citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139378/us-entry-in-atlanta-airport-atl-together-with-a-us-citizen?noredirect=1&lq=1)